# Parse HTML from a string with DOMParser and return Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, sorting, html-parsing

I'm successfully parsing HTML from a string using DOMParser but the output is not what I want.

This is the HTML Example I Have

[codesandbox url](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bash-wxp01?file=/src/index.js)

```js
    const html = `
      <h1>Lorem ipsum head 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 2</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 3</p>    
      <img src="http://www.exampleimage.com" />
      <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 4</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 5</p>
      <video src="http://www.examplevideo.com"></video>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum head 6</h1>    
    `;


    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const DOM = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

    const body = DOM.querySelector("body");

    const json = Array.from(body.children).map((element, i) => {
      if (element.tagName === "IMG") {
        return {
          type: "image",
          source: element.src
        };
      }

      if (element.tagName === "VIDEO") {
        return {
          type: "video",
          source: element.src
        };
      }

      return {
        type: "text",
        source: `<${element.tagName.toLowerCase()}>${
          element.innerText
        }</${element.tagName.toLowerCase()}>`
      };
    });

    console.log(json);
```

HTML Input

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum head 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 2</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 3</p>    
<img src="http://www.exampleimage.com" />
<p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 4</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 5</p>
<video src="http://www.examplevideo.com"></video>
<h1>Lorem ipsum head 6</h1>
```

The final output based on this HTML I was trying to achieve is this

```
// [
//   {
//     'type': 'text',
//     'source': '<h1>Lorem ipsum head 1</h1><p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 2</p><p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 3</p>'
//   },
//   {
//     'type': 'image',
//     'source': 'https://example.com/mJet2.jpg'
//   },
//   {
//     'type': 'text',
//     'source': '<p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 4</p><p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 5</p>'
//   },
//   {
//     'type': 'video',
//     'source': '<video src="http://www.examplevideo.com" />'
//   }
// ]
```

But the output I'm getting is for every tag I'm getting the object `{ type: 'text', source: '' }`, but I want to group text tags h1, p, p if they come in order and when it hit `<img /> or <video />` in that order I want those to be object like `{ type: 'image', source: 'url of img' }` and continue in that order. So basicly I want to keep order as represented in that HTML, but keep grouping HTML texts in one object as it showed in this above example.

If someone can help me with logic would be great because I can not figure this out

Comment: You should add your expected output to illustrate what you are trying to achieve @Indigo

Comment: @grodzi I already explain as you can see : The final output based on this HTML I was trying to achieve is this

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a context (the opened `h1`) and append it every `p` you encounter. Whenever you find another `h1`, override that context with the new `h1`.

Edit: misread the grouping. Expressed differently:
You want to group h1?, p* altogether.
Same idea holds:

Below using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of map to "ignore" the p tag (since already concatenated to the h1 context)

```js
const html = `
      <h1>Lorem ipsum head 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 2</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 3</p>    
      <img src="http://www.exampleimage.com" />
      <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 4</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum paragraph 5</p>
      <video src="http://www.examplevideo.com"></video>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum head 6</h1>    
      <p>onagain</p>
    `;


    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const DOM = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

    const body = DOM.querySelector("body");
    let lastOpenedTag = null
    const json = Array.from(body.children).flatMap((element, i) => {
      if (element.tagName === "IMG") {
        lastOpenedTag = null
        return {
          type: "image",
          source: element.src
        };
      }

      if (element.tagName === "VIDEO") {
        lastOpenedTag = null
        return {
          type: "video",
          source: element.src
        };
      }
      const back = {
        type: "text",
        source: `<${element.tagName.toLowerCase()}>${
          element.innerText
        }</${element.tagName.toLowerCase()}>`
      }
      if (element.tagName === 'P') {
        if (lastOpenedTag === null) {
          lastOpenedTag = back
        } else {
          lastOpenedTag.source += element.outerHTML
          return []
        }
      }
      if (element.tagName === 'H1') {
        lastOpenedTag = back
      }
      return back;
    });

    console.log(json);
```